# Install a distro from an online repository core make file

Tags: distributions, version-control, drush, aegir

I would like to use the hosting tool [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org) to install this distribution from a make file directly:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/elmsmedia/plain/drupal-org.make

what is the "workaround" to be able to insert the above URL as a string in Aegir platform make file field here:

[image: Create Platform]

I have tried a lot of distributions but all failed.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Drush Make infra does not support this use-case well.

The quickest wordaround is to clone the project Git repository and provide a local path to the makefile in the Aegir UI.

For elmsmedia I guess the best makefile would be http://cgit.drupalcode.org/elmsmedia/tree/local.make.example

OpanAtrium has http://cgit.drupalcode.org/openatrium/tree/build-openatrium.make for this same purpose.

Comment: thanks, I have tried to use the OpenAtrium make file, maybe it's my outdated version of Aegir, but it didn't work like expected: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/221652/db00d11630403085789da2f668dfe6f5

Comment: What did you priovide as a makefile path? ```/tmp/myopenatriumclone/build-openatrium.make```

Comment: i used the path you provided in the answer.

Comment: Which Aegir and Drush versions do you have?

Comment: ah of course!! i have Drush 4.6-dev and Aegir BOA-2.0.8. they must be too outdated, right?

Comment: Yes, fairly outdated